# Debugging go in vscode doesn't stop at breakpoints, says "Could not find file ..." when debugger starts

Tags: go, vscode-debugger, delve

Ubuntu. vscode 1.62.1. go1.17.3. vscode go extension v0.29.0. delve v1.7.1.

I'm new to vscode and Go.  I have many years of experience debugging Java apps in Eclipse.

I've constructed a small multi-module Go app.  I can set a breakpoint in main and other functions in other modules.  Inside main.go, I select "Start Debugging".

It starts the application, and I can tell it's working from the console, and that the REST endpoint responds with my dummy response.

However, it will NOT stop at breakpoints.  As soon as I start the session, the red breakpoint markers suddenly become hollow, and hovering on one of them shows a message "Could not find file ...", which prints the full path to the source file in question.

When I start it, it shows the following in the console:

> Starting: /home/.../go/bin/dlv-dap dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:43347 --log-dest=3 from /home/.../...
> DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:43347

I haven't modified the launch.json (I hope someday a friendlier interface to editing launch configurations is provided).

What else could I be doing wrong?

**Update**:

This is a screenshot showing main.go just before I press F5 (Start Debugging):

[image: Before pressing F5]

Notice that I have a breakpoint on the print statement, on the first line of main.

This is what I see after I press F5:

[image: After pressing F5]

Notice that it printed "At start of main" in the console.  It didn't stop at the breakpoint. Also notice message in tooltip when hovering over the breakpoint.

**Update**:

This is a view of my directory structure:

[image: project directory structure]

Comment: Could you also provide a screenshot of your current workspace? Does the root of your vscode workspace contain `main.go` or is it in a subdirectory?

Comment: main.go, along with go.mod and go.sum, are in the root.  Other modules are in subfolders (in different packages).

Comment: @aside what difference would it make if it is subdirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, just make sure you have initiated your project with `go mod init voltagems`: that would explain the `import "voltagems/xxx"`, but also helps [delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve) to find your `main.go` file at debug time.
You should have `go.mod` and `go.sum` files beside `main.go`.

Second, check your `go env` output, making sure [`GOPATH` and `GOROOT`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/configuring-goroot-and-gopath.html) are set to default paths.

The [OP David M. Karr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10508/david-m-karr) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69936099/debugging-go-in-vscode-doesnt-stop-at-breakpoints-says-could-not-find-file/69981080#comment123710117_69981080):

> I did run "`go mod init`" when I first created the project, but I realized that I didn't like the root module name, so I changed it to "`voltagems`"

I believe you can edit directly go.mod first line, and make sure it says:

```
module voltagems
```

Then `go mod verify` + `go mod tidy`

Finally, `go build .`. Restart your VSCode (or the command `Reload Window`), and see if the issue persists.

---

The [OP David M. Karr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10508/david-m-karr) points out to a root cause:

> There are **symbolic links** in my project path.
>
> There is a "`substitutePath`" configuration in VSCode-Go that is used to map to absolute paths.

You can see this parameter mentioned in [Debugging with Legacy Debug Adapter](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/2a9fb96555c7e6317119e4927ec807e32ce89ce9/docs/debugging-legacy.md#configuration)

> ### `substitutePath`
>
> Path mappings to apply to get from a path in the editor to a path in the compiled program (default: `[]`).

That comes from [issue 622](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/622) "`debug`: breakpoints don't work when working with symlink".
And [commit 93f32bb](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/commit/93f32bb42385de95bfce538295299d28b5cb5cee)

> ### `src/debugAdapter`: add `substitutePath` config for debugging
>
> This change adds a new configuration option to both launch and
> attach requests.
> `substituePath` takes an array that maps from string to string that is used to translate paths passed to the debugger and then
> back to the client.
>
> This allows users to translate their symlinked directories to the
> files that were actually used to build the binary.
> In addition this can also be used for remote debugging, and when the location of the files has moved since the program was built.

Example: you need a `from` and `to` key:

```json
    "substitutePath": [
        {
            "from": "/symlink/path/dir/on/local/machine",
            "to": "/absolute/path/dir/on/local/machine",
        },
```

Comment: I did run "go mod init" when I first created the project, but I realized that I didn't like the root module name, so I changed it to "voltagems". Can I just run that command again?  If this is what I needed, you'd think vscode-go would know something was out of sync and notified me with a warning of some type.

Comment: In the root of the project, I have go.mod, go.sun, and main.go.

Comment: GOPATH="/home/dk068x/go"; GOPATH="/home/dk068x/go"

Comment: @DavidM.Karr I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of that made any difference. Same result at the end. Is there a "delve" log file, and can we perhaps increase the log level for it?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Not that I know of (for instance https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1217). At this stage, I would create a new minimal go mod project in a new folder, just to see if the issue persists in said new project.

Comment: I've managed to resolve this. There are symbolic links in my project path. There is a "substitutePath" configuration in vscode-go (that I don't find much documentation for) that is used to map to absolute paths.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and added documentation around `substitutePath`.

Comment: And note that none of this documentation actually mentions the format that is actually required. It needs to say this exactly. It needs a map with keys named "from" and "to". Without that, people are just guessing.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Indeed. I have edited the answer to add an example, making that map visible for other readers.

Comment: substitudePath worked for me. Thanks.