# vscode ssh develop Go cannot stop at breakpoint when code under /home/{username}/ floder

Tags: linux, go, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have the remote develop problem. I want to ask for some advices to solve this problem.

1. when my code under `~/` floder, debug cannot stop at breakpoints:
   [image: case1-under home path]
2. when my code not under `~/` floder, debug normal!
   [image]
3. I tried to debug C file under `~/` floder, no problem, can stop at breakpoint

---

Tried:

1. I think if it is because of permission. so I run `sudo chmod 777 ~/code`, but not work.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#my-program-does-not-stop-at-breakpoints

Answer (score 1):

Check if, as [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981080/6309), there is no symlink in the project settings.

For mac, make sure go env does not include (as in [issue 2807](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2807#issuecomment-539177429)), `GOFLAGS="-trimpath"`

> The solution would be to add to your `launch.json`
>
> ```
> remotePath": "/myapp/"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for JetBrains-ssh-goland. I know why my remote linux cannot debug using vscode.

my `~` path is soft link to `/data00` path. so vscode cannot find file under `~/`.

But goland can find it and the absolute path I copied from goland is below:

[image: project path]

I don't know what is soft link right now, but I will find it out (╥﹏╥)
thanks.

Comment: explain soft-link & hard link in Chinese: https://www.jianshu.com/p/dde6a01c4094